# Retrieve multiple files using Get Api

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to retrieve multiple google files in a single get api call by specifying a comma separated list of fileIds.
Ex: fileId = fileId1,fileId2,fileId3, will this retrieve all the 3 files in a single get call?

I tried passing a single fileId and returns me the result, when I tried comma separated list it return object not found error.

I am expecting to get all the files specified by the fileId.

Answer (score 0):

[File.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) will return a list of files.

> Lists or searches **files**.

[File.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) is singular and will only get a single file denoted by the file id you send it.

> Gets **a** file's metadata or content by ID

[image]

File.get does no support more then one file id.

Comment: Which API will support this kind of requirement? Where I can send a comma separated list of fileIDs that I want to fetch.

Comment: That would probably depend upon the system whos files you are trying to access wither or not they support comma separated file ids.    In the case of the Google drive api it does not support this.